# Selenium 2 WebDriver NoClassDefFoundErrorS

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with `Selenium 2 WebDriver` in Eclipse and everything works fine.

But when I want to test my WebDriver Testcases without Eclipse many missing classes occur.

First it startet with :

```
NoClassDefFoundError com/google/common/collect/Maps
```

so I downloaded the guava.jar and set the classpath to it.

But now the next NoClassDefFoundError occured:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
```

The errors always occur on `createDriver();`

I run the Selenium with JUnit in Java.

"JUnit only"-testcases work fine (set the classpath to junit.jar & selenium-java.jar)

Do you know which jars I have to bind in that eclipse already has bound in as default for the selenium testcases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using a standalone server download?

If you download the selenium server package  you'll get about 47 jars with it. I believe you need all of those jars in your classpath in order to execute.  That package can be downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-2.20.0.zip&can=2&q=)

Or the standalone package can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar

If you're not using it right now, the easiest solution might be to switch to the standalone version; otherwise download the full server & add all the jars to your classpath.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just wanted to post the same answer too, found it on the selenium page. Working now!