# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps - Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Dear Selenium Experts,

I have come across the following run-time error from a JPA 2.0 program which appears to be related to Firefox Profile for some reason:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.(FirefoxProfile.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.(FirefoxProfile.java:79)
    at model.DownloadCarDetail.getMercedezDetail(model.DownloadCarDetail:72)
    at model.DownloadCarDetail.getMercedezDetail.main    (model.DownloadCarDetail.getMercedezDetail.java:47)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
Java Result: 1
```

I have kept Firefox to version 15 so that it is supported by Selenium Webdriver but suspect that the issue is to do with not able to read profile directory.

Your assistance would be very much apprecaited.

Many thanks,

George

Answer (score 19):

The problem you are seeing has nothing to do with your Firefox profile.

Actually, it is the JVM classloader that complains that it can't find the `com.google.common.collect.Maps` class.

This usually means that you don't have [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (which is a dependency for Selenium) on your classpath. Clean and rebuild your project, check your classpath, check the various versions of libraries that might be there. If you're using some kind of dependency management system (Maven, Ivy etc.), check it's configured right.

Answer (score 3):

Import the .jar file to Eclipse downloaded from [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release23) (depending on the current version).

Comment: downloading the jar file from this link and adding it to the classpath solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

open this link https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and download Java  3.11.0(current version) open zip file to desktop on netbeans or eclips click add jars/file in selenium-java-3.11.0\libs select all file also in selenium-java-3.11.0 select client-combined-3.11.0.jar you will be ok. dont remember to add `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");` code. you can download chromedriver this link https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.38/

Comment: Where to add this line --> System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Guava dependency was corrupt. Worked fine after I deleted the corrupt jars and rebuilt whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for offerring your suggestion for a solution to this issue. I have found the exact answer from [Selenium 2 WebDriver NoClassDefFoundErrorS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699997/selenium-2-webdriver-noclassdeffounderrors) which has resolved the underlying issue.

George

Answer (score -2):

add below maven dependency and clean and compile your code.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.common/google-collect -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```