# Exception by using SafariDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run selenium safari driver.
My code is: `driver = new SafariDriver();`

But I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:42)
    at com.ca.automation.utils.WebDriverFactory.initWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:168)
    at com.ca.automation.utils.WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:210)
    at com.ca.automation.utils.BaseSelenium.<init>(BaseSelenium.java:43)
    at com.ca.automation.pb.strategicPlanning.CrudDriversBTest.<init>(CrudDriversBTest.java:20)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, by any chance are you getting:  [WARNING] The POM for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:2.44.0 is missing, no dependency information available

Answer (score 1):

There could be a solution: [Selenium 2 WebDriver NoClassDefFoundErrorS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699997/selenium-2-webdriver-noclassdeffounderrors). You just need to use the standalone version or add all the jars to the build path.